# Pass Enum value as CommandParameter when the Enum is in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am still learning WPF Binding and have been struggling with this for a while.  I have an enum store inside the ViewModel like so:

```
namespace theNamespace
{
    public class frmSetupViewModel
    {
        public enum LocationLabelType {Location, Sample}
        ...
    }
}
```

And I would like have a button pass one of the values via the CommandParameter but cannot figure out how to get it to work.  So far, these are the combinations I have tried:

```
//When value is inside the frmSetupViewModel, these do not work
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:LocationLabelType.Location}" //'Type  was not found.'
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:frmSetupViewModel+LocationLabelType.Location}" //'Type was not found.'
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:frmSetupViewModel.LocationLabelType.Location}" //'Type was not found.'

CommandParameter="{Binding {x:Static local:LocationLabelType.Location}}" //'Value cannot be null'
CommandParameter="{Binding {x:Static local:frmSetupViewModel+LocationLabelType.Location}}" //'Value cannot be null'
CommandParameter="{Binding {x:Static local:frmSetupViewModel.LocationLabelType.Location}}" //'Value cannot be null'
```

But if I move the enum OUTSIDE the VM and into the name space like this:

```
namespace theNamespace
{
    public enum LocationLabelType {Location, Sample}

    public class frmSetupViewModel
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

this works just fine:

```
//Works when enum is moved to Namespace
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:LocationLabelType.Location}"
```

I assume I am missing something with my CommandParameter?

The VM is loaded via DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:frmSetupViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This work fine:

```
CommandParameter="{x:Static uiTest:MainWindow+LocationLabelType.Location}"
```

You ran the project with this code?
WPF designer can show this error `//'Type was not found.'` if you don't build the project, because it does not see the type of enum.

Comment: Thanks, that does work actually!  So is there a way to suppress the error in the Desginer?  Otherwise, I will not be able to see the view.

Comment: Thanks.  No Dice.  Tried build, cleaning, rebuilding, nothing seems to get it.  Seems I have to live with it in the namespace if I want to use the designer :/.  This is VS2010, is VS2012 any better with WPF?